# Change the TextView everytime a search query is made

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get this code to show whatever is typed in search view as a text in the textview of the layout. But when I run the app nothing is shown.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     TextView textview;
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.layout_search);
     textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.search_result);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu,menu);
          SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_box).getActionView();
          searchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
          searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

          searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
               @Override
               public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String search){
               return false;
               }

               @Override
               public boolean onQueryTextChange(String search){
                    String result= "You have searched for "+search;
                    textview.setText(result);
                    return false;
               }
          });

          return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     }
 }
```

What should I do to show the search the search string in textview?

**edit**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
     <item android:id="@+id/search_box"
          android:title="search here"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
          app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

When I enter a search query to the search box it isn't being shown on the textview widget on the layout.

Comment: Please add the menu layout xml to your post. Also please explain what you mean by "But when I run the app nothing is shown."

Comment: added the menu layout xml to the question

Comment: Please add `layout_search.xml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also be interested in looking at databinding to solve this problem:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/

From this page:

`<TextView
    android:text="@{viewmodel.userName}" />`

Answer (score 0):

To update a UI object you must use the main thread, in your code you is updating the `textview` on another thread. Try change your method `onQueryTextChange` to use the main thread to update your `TextView`.

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String search){
      String result= "You have searched for "+search;
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textview.setText(result);
        }
      });
      return false;
}
```

Comment: All code instructions executed inside `onQueryTextChange()` are executed on the UI thread. Your suggestion of adding `runOnUiThread()` does nothing.